# Mocking attribute to change each time it is accessed

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Here is the function I want to test:

```
def send_something():
    conn = lib.conn.SSH1
    conn.open()
    conn.send('ls\n')
    if 'home' not in conn.recbuf:
        return lib.FAIL

    conn.send('whoami\n')
    if USER not in conn.recbuf:
        return lib.FAIL
    return lib.PASS
```

Every time I call conn.send() the output of the call is stored in conn.recbuf. To test this I need conn.recbuf to be different each time it is called. (I know I could just change conn.recbuf to be a string that contains both home and USER but that won't work for more complicated functions)

Here is what I have come up with so far in my test:

```
@mock.patch.object(demo_sequence.lib, 'conn')
def test_send_something(mock_conn):
    mock_conn.SSH1.recbuf = 'home'
    assert demo_sequence.lib.PASS == demo_sequence.send_something()
    mock_conn.SSH1.send.assert_any_call('ls\n')
    mock_conn.SSH1.send.assert_any_call('whoami\n')
```

Obviously this fails because conn.recbuf is only 'home' and does not contain USER.

I need something like conn.recbuf.side_effect = ['home', USER] but will work when just referencing recbuf and not calling it.

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to mock `send` so that it doesn't do anything other than update `recbuff`? It's hard to provide a good solution without knowing what type` conn` actually is.

Comment: The conn library is weird (bad). SSH1 also has to be mocked because it doesn't always exist. That is why I chose to mock as the lib.conn level.

Comment: I might also recommend that instead of hard-coding the value of `conn` in `send_something`, you make it a function argument. Then you can pass any object you want as an argument instead of having to use `mock.patch` at all.

Comment: If you are unit testing send_something, then it's probably better to mock conn entirely. It is also possible to make another, special kind of test for the lib.conn library if you want to see it fulfills the contract. Also, it is possible to make a shim / adapter around "bad" library - if your code uses the library in many places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to change conn.recbuf to be a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property), you could use a [PropertyMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) to achieve the desired effect.

```
from unittest import mock

class Dummy:

    def __init__(self, myattribute):
        self._myattribute = myattribute

    @property
    def myattribute(self):
        return self._myattribute

def test():
    with mock.patch('__main__.Dummy.myattribute', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock) as mocked_attribute:
        mocked_attribute.side_effect = [4,5,6]
        d = Dummy("foo")
        print(d.myattribute)
        print(d.myattribute)
        print(d.myattribute)
```

However for your actual problem I think the comments to your question seem to include reasonable approaches.

Comment: This approach does satisfy my need. I have seen a few comments and previous answers that said to use PropertyMock but I never checked if recbuf was a real property. (has the property decorator). 
Thanks for the further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `side_effect`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Let's say `mock` is your mock object. Then you can do this:

```
mock.side_effect = [a,b,c]
```

then each time you call `mock`, the next value from the list is returned.

```
mock() # -> a
mock() # -> b
mock() # -> c
```

Comment: Downvoted because this is exactly what still learning mentioned in his last sentence and also explained why it is not working: he needs exactly this behavior for attributes and not callables.

Comment: Got it. You can achieve the same thing for attributes by mocking the `__getattr__` method but that might be a bit convoluted.

Comment: Can you elaborate on mocking __getattr__ to achieve a solution to my issue?

Comment: When you do a.x, it gets translated to a.__getattr__('x'). So you can try mocking that.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrangling with a similar issue earlier and found a solution using the `PropertyMock`. In my case I wanted to store a value elsewhere in the test case to assert against by calling a method via a `side_effect` when a property was set on the class I was mocking.

I think it should work for your case as well (if I've understood what you're trying to do).

The solution is to use a `PropertyMock` for your property `recbuf` and put the `side_effect` in there:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, PropertyMock

conn = MagicMock()
type(conn).recbuf = PropertyMock(side_effect=['home', USER])
```

The side effect will be called whenever the property `recbuf` is accessed, in this case iterating through `['home', USER]` each time. I guess you'll need to patch that `USER` value too so you don't get a name error.

Hope this works / helps!